# Android Lollipop not displaying H or E symbol when Data is on

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

I just updated my Moto G (1st gen) from KitKat to Lollipop. Everything is great except two days after loading the update, the symbol displaying 3G (H) or 2G (E) stopped showing either even when data is up and running. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it shows 'R' ?

Answer (score -2):

**For Moto G (1st Generation)**:

Goto "**Settings**". Under "**Wireless & networks**" select "**...More**", then select "**Mobile networks**". Select "**Access point names**", click on "**+**" to add new APN.

Name: **Aircel GPRS**

APN: **aircelgprs**

Proxy: not set

Port: not set

Username: not set

Password: not set

Server: not set

MMSC: not set

MMS proxy: not set

MMS port: not set

MCC: **405**

MNC: **803**

Authentication type: not set

APN type: **default,supl**

APN protocol: **IPv4**

APN roaming protocol: **IPv4**

Bearer: Unspecified

==============

**MCC** **MNC** for different states:

404 17 WB

404 25 Bihar

404 28 Odissa

404 29 Assam

404 37 J&K

404 41 Chennai

404 42 TN

404 91 Kolkata

405 800 Delhi & NCR

405 801 Andhra Pradesh

405 802 Gujarat

405 803 Karnataka

405 804 Maharastra & Goa

405 805 Mumbai

405 806 Rajasthan

405 807 Haryana

405 808 MP

405 809 Kerala

405 810 UP (East)

405 811 UP (West)

405 812 Punjab

==================

Save it, and select it as your default APN. After this, '**H**' symbol gets displayed.