# Update to 4.4.4 from 4.4.2 Kitkat, mobile data unavaliable

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mobile-data

I hadn't updated my software since 4.4.2 on my S5 and just updated it today. However, after updating to 4.4.4, my mobile data stopped working, I can still make calls and connect to WiFi, but mobile data does not work anymore. I even tried a factory restore but that did not help. Anyone ever experience this problem?

Comment: Check your APN settings and make sure they are correct. APN settings are dependant on your carrier, but you can [look at this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98210/android-lollipop-not-displaying-h-or-e-symbol-when-data-is-on/101573#101573) here as it will show you sort of what you need to set if your APN is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

> full wipe with wipe cache,

**remember ;**

> OTA Update not recomended.

easily, download last android version from SamMobile , then with odin flash it.
check last firmware :

> http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/

goodluck.